# Normalize data with index from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (call it tblContractor) like so: (first row in intentionally empty):

```
ContractorId ContractorName LicenseNumber  
0  
1 Smith Inc A12345  
43 Joe's LLC B4C5t6  
4 SureFix Co. 77987  
77 ReadyMix 009ABCV
```

and a table tblProject like so:

```
ProjectId Name ContractorName ContractorId    
32  SureFix Co.     NULL   
40  Joe's LLC   NULL  
42  ReadyMix    NULL  
44  Smith Inc   NULL
```

I've just created that last column, ContractorId, because I want to normalize the data, 
i.e. have the ContractorName in only tblContractor and an index to the Contractor in tblProject.
So tblProject will look like:

```
ProjectId Name ContractorName ContractorId  
32  SureFix Co      77987  
40  Joe's LLC   B4C5t6  
42  ReadyMix    009ABCV  
44  Smith Inc   A12345
```

How do I do this?

This is what I've go so far but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT project.ProjectId, project.Name, project.ContractorName, project.ContractorId
FROM tblProject project 
WHERE NOT EXISTS  ( 
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM tblContractor contractor 
    WHERE project.ContractorName = contractor.ContractorName)
Order by ContractorName
```

Sorry for the table formatting. I looked at the questions about table formatting for SO questions and I guess there really isn't a good way to do it.

Comment: Is "SureFix Co" and "SureFix Co." a typo? In the real data do these actually match? This is pretty painful here to work with. Glad you are trying to fix the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try starting with this to get the contractorid data moved over:

```
update a set a.contractorid=b.contractorid from tblProject a
join tblContractor  b on a.name=b.name
```

Comment: @AlLelopath, then you can just drop the other 2 columns from the project table